# passing multiple parameters to routerLink

Tags: angular

I want to use routerLink to navigate to another component , here is my route definition

```typescript
{path: 'articles/:id/edit-translation/:translation_id',component: ArticleEditTranslationComponent}
```

what is the correct format to pass theses 2 params (id,translation_id) to routerLink ?

Comment: for now I got it working using routerLink instead of [routerLink] and rendering out the values manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a [routerLink]="['/articles', id, 'edit-translation', translation_id]"> link to another component</a>
```

For more reference, https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink and https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `id` is 1 and `translation_id` is 2. Then you could use it like bellow example

```typescript
  <a [routerLink]="['/articles/1/edit-translation/2']">
    link to component
  </a>
```

Also if you need to use `id` and `translation_id` as variables in the component

in component

```typescript
  id = 1;
  translation_id = 2;
```

in component template you could use like this : Refer the [DOC](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description) for more details

```typescript
<a [routerLink]="['/articles', id, 'edit-translation', translation_id]">
  link to component
</a>
```

or like bellow way

```typescript
<a [routerLink]="['/articles/'+ id +'/edit-translation/'+ translation_id]">
  link to component
</a>
```

Comment: that's correct , but I was looking for this format 

[routerLink]="['/hero', hero.id]"

Comment: yes also you could use like that '/articles', id, 'edit-translation', translation_id

Comment: your last edit was the one i was looking for .. however someone got it correct before that last edit .. thanks anyway ... upvoted your answer